# How to view SQL genarated by the Entity Framework Core with in-memory provider?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I want to view SQL generated by Linq in EF Core, but when the database is in-memory, there are no string SQL data.

I use `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` (7.0.4),  `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` (7.0.10), Visual Studio 2022.

```
.... 
// example of how I configure DbContext
DbContextOptions<CollectorContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CollectorContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(dbName)


// example of how I query data
var builtInParameterGrQuary = db.RevitBuiltInParameterGroups
    .Where(x => !modelData.RevitBuiltInParameterGroups
            .Select(d => d.Name)
            .Contains(x.Name));
var str = builtInParameterGrQuary.ToQueryString();
```

The variable `str` shows me:

> There is no query string because the in-memory provider does not use a string-based query language

The same message was in the DebugView of the `EntityQueryable` class.

[DebugView for entity query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFfKD.png)

How to view SQL generated data when database is in-memory?

Comment: The message is *very* clear, although the question isn't. SQL is a query language, not data. The in-memory provider [wraps dictionary containers](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/release/8.0/src/EFCore.InMemory/Storage/Internal/InMemoryTable.cs), it doesn't use SQL queries. The LINQ queries are applied to the in-memory data directly

Comment: Why are you asking this? What is the *actual* problem? If you want to eg test query logging, you can use the SQLite provider in in-memory mode

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks for response! Actualy, I'm new in EF Core and I've started with tests. Test environment was set to work with memory not with the real database. So, I wrote some LINQ code and wanted to see what actual it wound look like in database query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In memory database don't generate any SQL scripts. It is  based on general data collection like List. You can only generate SQL if you are working against real DB like SQL server, SQL Lite ..etc . You can also log generated SQL to console.

1. Adjust dbcontext class to take  db context options.

```
public class CollectorContext : DbContext
{
   .........
   .........

    public CollectorContext()
    {
        
    }
    public PublisherDBContext(DbContextOptions<CollectorContext> options)
        :base(options)
    {
        
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    { 
        if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {

        }
```

2. Generate db context with required logging option.

```
   var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CollectorContext>()
                              .UseNpgsql("connection string")
                               .LogTo(Console.WriteLine
                               , new[] { DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name }
                               , LogLevel.Information)
                                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

   db = new CollectorContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

Comment: Deepak Koshy, thanks for the response! That it! I'm new in EF Core. My mistake was, that I hope the EF Core make sql quary, but it doesn't, because I have no realy database. Thanks!